# Difference of sums

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I take no credit for this challenge at all. It's [Project Euler problem 6](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=6):

> The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is,
>   1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 10<sup>2</sup> = 385
>
> The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is,
>   (1 + 2 + ... + 10)<sup>2</sup> = 55<sup>2</sup> = 3025
>
> Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural
>   numbers and the square of the sum is 3025 − 385 = 2640.
>
> Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred 
>   natural numbers and the square of the sum.

I became interested in some code golfing here when I noticed my solution (in Python) was very, very short. I want to see how some other languages (perl, I'm looking at you!) can bring it in this simple problem.

So, what is the shortest possible way to solve this problem? Shortest means fewest characters in source code.

**NOTE: bonus points for solving for the first n natural numbers.**

Comment: Thank you to the SO gods for making this a CW question.

Comment: Why do I feel that some folk will write loops to solve this question :)

Comment: I assume that just printing the answer (25164150) in your language of choice subverts the intent of this question.

Comment: You should change it to ask for the first *n* natural numbers, not the first 100. Otherwise the shortest solution is simply to hardcode the result.

Comment: A frankly boring problem to golf.

Comment: @Eric Towers: not really, project Euler requires only the answer, not a general solution: you don't have to show your work...

Comment: Precomputation is a valid solution to problems - @Rafe Kettler, how about changing the challenge to colving for the first `n` natural numbers where `n` can be any natural number under some reasonable limit?

Comment: @jball: seems reasonable. I'll edit the question.

Comment: posting projecteuler problems is lame.

Comment: @dmckee: it's boring in a high level language with functional programming tools (e.g. Python or Haskell

Comment: If you're interested in code golf & programming puzzles, there's a proposal for a site dedicated to those on Area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles?referrer=zK0hq5BpXABqY44vShJFww2 Commit to it, and spread the word for others to do so, so we can have a dedicated site for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Almost Any Language:  20 chars.

```
(n*n-1)*(3*n+2)*n/12
```

Answer (score 8):

## 40/<s>49</s> 43 characters; should work in most languages

```
n=100;(n*(n+1)/2)**2-n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6;
```

Should work in some languages;

```
n=100;n*(n+1)*n*(n+1)/4-n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6;
```

This should work in most of the languages.

Note that `1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6` and `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2`

**EDIT**: oh and for the bonus you just remove the first 6 chracters.

Comment: please, there is a typo in the note for the formula of sum of squares: the denominator should be 6.

Comment: That was exactly my solution. Note that for the second, you can save a bit (6 characters) by moving the `/2` out: `n=100;n*(n+1)*n*(n+1)/4-n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6`

Comment: Applying some algebra to this gets you down to 17 characters, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since the "intelligent" solution (that comes from two simple math proofs) has been already posted by @Gabi Purcaru and short solutions for such problem are easy, instead I'll post a *long* solution based on template metaprogramming, I don't think it's so easy to make it longer without putting in useless garbage/whitespace/....

## C++ - <s>648</s> 659 chars

```
#include <iostream>

template<int Num>
struct Square
{
    static const int Value = Num*Num;
};

template<int Num>
struct NatSum
{
    static const int Value=Num+NatSum<Num-1>::Value;
};

template<>
struct NatSum<0>
{
    static const int Value = 0;
};

template<int Num>
struct SquaresSum
{
    static const int Value=Square<Num>::Value+SquaresSum<Num-1>::Value;
};

template<>
struct SquaresSum<0>
{
    static const int Value = 0;
};

template<int Num>
struct DifferenceOfSums
{
    static const int Value = Square<NatSum<Num>::Value>::Value - SquaresSum<Num>::Value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<DifferenceOfSums<100>::Value<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now enjoy your challenge result calculated at compile time and put directly in the executable. :)

Comment: meh... I know why there aren't gode golfs for longest answers.. :P Btw. is anyone thinking this is more readable than a golfed version?

Comment: Wonderful and it's the fastest one too! (For runtime anyway, not compile time).

Answer (score 4):

Perl 15 chars:

```
 print 25164150;
```

Comment: I remember participating in a programming competition where the winners hardcoded answers for one of the problems.  Technically it gave the correct output so they were awarded full points xD

Comment: @Matteo, in my defence I wrote this before the requirement to solve for `N` was added :o)

Comment: python 14 chars: print 25164150. Haha, bested.

Comment: Semi column isn't needed, so 12 chars : say 25164150

Answer (score 4):

## Octave: 28 chars

```
v=1:100;sum(v)**2-sum(v.*v)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica "Guessing the Answer"

Mathematica is able to "guess" the function that generates some sequences.

So, If you calculate the first six terms for this problem, the result is:

```
 {0, 4, 22, 70, 170, 350}
```

Now we can enter that sequence to the "sequences oracle", and get the function:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{0, 4, 22, 70, 170, 350}]
```

Mathematica answers:

```
1/12 (#-1) (2 # + 5 #^2 + 3 #^3) &
```

which is the formula posted anywhere in the other answers.

So we can calculate the 100th term using the first six terms ... without knowing how to generate them!

```
In> FindSequenceFunction[{0, 4, 22, 70, 170, 350}][100]
Out> 25164150
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica 17 chars:**
After applying `FullSimplify`

```
n(n^2-1)(3n+2)/12
```

**Mathematica 27 chars:**
As it doesn't require those pesky multiplication symbols...

```
(n(n+1))^2/4-n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

Or in vector form,
**Mathematica <strike>28</strike>25 chars:** after reviewing the other [Mathematica answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981887/difference-of-sums/3982124#3982124), I was able to shave off another 3 chars

```
Plus@@#^2-#.#&@Range[100]
```

Comment: I love how the syntax highlighting feature doesn't even recognize most of your code as real code.

Comment: Yes.  It is very easy to write line noise in Mathematica.

Comment: Plus@@#^2-#.#&@Range[#]&  .... one char less and then evaluate as %[100] ... or %[n] for bonus points

Answer (score 2):

## 17 or 18 characters

```
(3n/2+1)(n^3-n)/6
(3n/2+1)(n**3-n)/6
```

depending on how your language does exponents

Edit: well, 20 characters `(3*n/2+1)*(n**3-n)/6` if your language doesn't understand implicit multiplication... but Mathematica does.

Comment: Easy enough to do without exponents, simply expand the exponent for a cost of an additional 2 chars `n^3` == `n*n*n`.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 19 characters

`(12%~]*<:@*:*2+3*])`

This just calculates n(n^2-1)(3n+2)/12.

### J, 21 characters

`(([:*:+/)-[:+/*:)i.>:`

This actually generates the list of natural numbers up to N (`i.>:`), then calculates the sum of squares `[:*:+/` and square of sums `[:+/*:`, then subtracts them.

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
Math.Pow(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum(), 2)-
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => i*i).Sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.x, 48 characters

```
a=range(n+1)
print sum(a)**2-sum(x*x for x in a)
```

I originally wrote it in Python 3.x, which is 49 characters:

```
a=range(n+1)
print(sum(a)**2-sum(x*x for x in a))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell - 33 chars

```
g x=sum.map(\y->(y-1)*y*y)$[2..x]
```

edit:

To make a full program we need 79 chars

```
import System
main=getArgs>>=print.(\x->sum.map(\y->(y-1)*y*y)$[2..x]).read.head
```

Answer (score 1):

### Golfscript - 17 chars

```
~:).*(3)*2+*)*12/
```

Reads number from stdin\

### 23 chars to generate the first 100

```
100,{:).*(3)*2+*)*12/}%
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was also short...

```
def euler6(limit):
    """
    calculate the difference between the sum of the squares of
    the first n natural numbers and the square of the sum of
    the same n natural numbers.

      >>> euler6(10)
      2640


    """
    sequence = range(limit+1)
    squares = sum(map(lambda x: x*x, sequence))
    sums = sum(sequence)
    sums *= sums
    return sums-squares
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
v = numpy.arange(100)
print sum(v)**2 - sum(v*v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica:
brute force (39 chars, 6 removable):

```
    Plus@@# ^2 - Plus@@ (#^2) &@ Range[100]
```

by means of math, on the fly (70 chars, 24 removable -- we don't *have* to simplify, specify lower limits, or use a 3 character function name):

```
    In[1]:= foo[k_] = Simplify[Sum[n, {n, 1, k}]^2 - Sum[n^2, {n, 1, k}]]
            foo[100]
    Out[1]= 1/12 k (-2 - 3 k + 2 k^2 + 3 k^3)
    Out[2]= 25164150
```

by means of previously performed math (40 chars, 11 removable)

```
    1/12 # (-2 - 3 # + 2 #^2 + 3 #^3) &@ 100
```

How short this can be depends on how much prior computation we permit.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 41 Chars

This is a 'proper' attempt.

**Code**: `$c+=$_**2,$e+=$_ for 0..pop;print$e**2-$c`

**Usage**:

```
$ perl -e '$c+=$_**2,$e+=$_ for 0..pop;print$e**2-$c' 100
25164150
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica  8 chars

**"My In is your Out"**

```
  In> 25164150
  Out> 25164150
```

`25164150`  is a full valid Mathematica expression that can be evaluated on its own.

Answer (score 0):

### Oracle SQL - 82 chars

```
select sum(l)*sum(l)-sum(l*l) from (select level l from dual connect by level<=:n)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is solution in a C** **cheers**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.
int main()
{
   int sum1=0,sum2=0,psum=0;

   for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
   sum1+=i*i;

   for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
   psum+=i;
   sum2=psum*psum;

   printf("\nDifference is: %d\n",sum2-sum1);


}
```